How can I configure Adobe Bridge so that it shows thumbnails for my videos?
Adobe Bridge doesn't show thumbnails for my videos:


How can I configure Adobe Bridge so that it shows thumbnails for my videos?

I can't directly answer your specific problem, but I can offer my setup for Adobe Bridge, which has no problem displaying video previews which scrub when the mouse pointer is moved across them.
My hardware and software:

MacBook Air 12-inch 2017
Processor 1.8 GHz Dual Core i5
MacOS Monterey Version 12.7.6
Adobe Bridge 2024 version 14.1.3.304

This is a screenshot of the preview panel showing one MP4 file and one folder

Filetypes Bridge will preview: MP4, MOV, M4A (audio only), JPG, PDF, PNG.
This is Bridge's behavior after its most recent Creative Cloud update. I did not have to make any adjustments to preferences for it to preview these files.

Thanks, I'll try updating

FWIW I just let Creative Cloud apps update themselves. Given the age and configuration of my hardware/software I'm surprised CC will still update for me.
